# Bios Raid and Windows that wants to format them

Tags: windows-7, bios, raid

I shutdown my PC improperly by holding down the power button. Now Windows sees 2 HDD's with a RAW filesystem instead of my RAID. After the fast shutdown my raid went though the "Verify" stage with 0 errors.

I have a RAID 1 set through my BIOS, on Windows I have "Intel Rapid Storage Technology" that displays my  RAID's status.

I am freaking out... there's all my data on those 2 drives and it's ironic that it's the RAID thing making me lose my data.

How can I restore my RAID setup?

Comment: Remember, **RAID is not a backup**

Comment: Yes, now I see it... I hope it's not too late.

Comment: No one.........?

Comment: Patience, young obi. It's only been a couple hours

Comment: My life is on those HDs :(

Comment: I just advertised this question in our [chat]; hopefully someone can help... I unfortunately can't

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem recovering ALL my data with no loss what-so-ever! I am so happy!

I passed a couple of really scary days but fortunatly I managed to recover my data! Here is what I did:

I searched for a software that could Recover RAID partitions and I found "DiskInternals Raid Recovery" which, after ~10h of scan found my files. Once I did that I recovered most of my files, some corrupted though, but more than I could hope for! But wait, there is a twist!

I decided to DELETE my raid configuration from the BIOS. The bios informed me that I will lose all the data, but that's a lie, you only lose your partition table or something like that, your data is still there!

Now I opened the tool that I use for managing partitions here on Windows called "Minitool Partition Manager". And did the following:

I selected my 2 disks (1 per time) that were on the RAID, right click > Recover partition. Then I selected "fast scan" and in 1 sec it founded 2 partitions (which was not possible, since I had only 1 partition per disk!).

I had 2 partitions because the first one was overlapping with the second (good) one! I don't know how to explain this... but I selected only the "good" partition and I restored it! Next I assigned a driver letter and changed it's serial number and now windows sees my 2 partitions without problems and without any data loss!

So if you ever find yourself i this situation, please consider using "Minitool Partition Manager". It's free and it just saved my data :)